# For desktop applications, how to get Facebook access_token from Browser?

Tags: facebook, desktop-application, access-token

I'm writing a Facebook plugin for my desktop application. Once user authorizes application, the access token will be appended to callback URL. If I will use regular browser (I don't like to use any html module in my app), then question is how can I get that token back to my desktop program?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> With the Device flow, a user presses a button on their device. The device then displays a short code generated by Facebook, and the user then types this code into Facebook in a standard web-browser in order to authorize that device to access their Facebook data.
>
> Please note that we are currently testing Device Authentication with a limited number of partners. It is not currently available for general use, and we are not accepting additional applications for access.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/devices/

Comment: Thanks your answer. So user has to enter the code when authorizing. There seems no easier way for a desktop app...right?